# How to identify which new rows were added in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
name   position  zipcode 
-------------------------
Gary   Gm          12345 
Rob    VP          54321 
John   Manager      1234
```

After 20 minutes some rows were added in the source and now the table looks like

```
name   position  zipcode 
------------------------
Gary   Gm          12345 
Rob    VP          54321 
John   Manager      1234
Chris  Director     5478 
Kane   VP           9999
```

So Kane and Chris were added after 20 minutes in the source, and there is no date time field to identify on which day the rows were added, I just wanted to know if there are any functions to identify the newly added rows in the table in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: All you can do is look at the transaction log ( https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3076/how-to-read-the-sql-server-database-transaction-log/ ) but it doesn't contain *reliable* per-row timestamps (only checkpoint timestamps). If you need an auditing solution then you should use SQL Server Change Tracking, which needs to be preemptively enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server

Comment: @Dai Thank you for the information, and this will help me to do research on how to figure out.

Comment: Add a `DATETIME2(n)` column to your table, if you really need to know when new rows have been added - or if you need to trap the moment of insertion, add an `AFTER INSERT` trigger to the table